# Rendering an invisible occluder

Tags: 2d, directx-10

I'm currently upgrading from a DirectDraw system (yeah I know, it's very old) to DirectX10.  It's a 2D system but simulates real world as each object has a range/depth in meters.  There is a background image that is rendered and kept on the farthest z-order.  All other objects are drawn on top of it and scaled according to what their range/depth would be.  However, there is a certain type of object I have that is defined as a polygon and renders a bit different.  It acts as an invisible occluder.  For instance, an occluder is at a range/depth of 40 (my units are meters) and is defined by 5 vertices (a pentagon) in the middle of the viewport.  There is a sprite object at the same viewport position but at a range/depth of 50.  The desired output is to have the sprite object not rendered, but the background should be seen through both of them.  So in essence these are invisible occluders, except that they do not occlude the background.

As a note, the occluders and the sprites all derive from the same base object type and are mixed together in a depth-sorted container.

My idea was to override the occluders Render method so they draw to a render target writing the range/depth values.  I then would render the sprites as normal, but in the vertex or pixel shader would compare the range value of the sprite with the range values in the render target.  However, it seems to me that I'd have to potentially read/write from the render target in the same pass before Present is called, and that's undefined.  If i was to render the occluders, unbind the render target and pass the texture in for a lookup by the other objects, I'll have to convert the sprite positions into that texture space which may be non-trivial.  Are either of these methods possible?

After thinking some more about it, one other idea came to mind.  I could take the occluders and set their texture coordinates in reference to the background texture.  In this way they would draw the same color values as the background, and because of the sorting if a sprite was behind it the user would still see the "background" but really it's the occluder looking like it.

Sorry if this is less a question and more thinking out loud, but I wanted to get impressions and ideas on the best way to go about this.  Seems to me I have options but wasn't certain which was most efficient and which is easiest.  Thanks in advance for any responses.

Comment: So I went with setting the texture coordinates in reference to the background image.  It ended up being a fairly easy process, the real fun part was doing the polygon triangulation to get the filled polygon to even use the texture coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in my comments I went with setting the texture coordinates in reference to the background image and then making sure the occluder, which was a simple polygon, was triangulated properly to make use of those texture coordinates.